# Gradle execute command with quotes

Tags: git, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to grab the commit messages from the commits done on git for the past 24 hour. So I tried this command in Gradle:

```
  def lastCommit = 'git rev-list -n1 --before="24 hours" --first-parent origin/develop'.execute()
```

to catch that last commit within my range. However I am getting the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> fatal: ambiguous argument 'hours"': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
  Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
  'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I am unable to find a way for gradle to properly process that "24 hours" argument properly and escape the quotes without breaking the execution.